# When I use the VLOOKUP function in excel where I'm trying to get a letter grade from a number set, I'm not getting the right letter

Tags: excel, function

I have my excel function and table here. Q2 is the output and I just rewrote the function in Q3

[image]

Comment: Please include all the necessary details in the question, not as links.

Comment: you need to sort the lookup table ascending on the Grade column.

Comment: If you have Excel365 then `XLookup()` would be best choice.

Comment: Just curious, is there no 'E' between D & F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `TRUE` as the forth criterion the lookup must be sorted ascending:

[image]

See the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) look under common problems.

Comment: @JacksonSmith if this helped, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have an accepted answer, but thought I would add another in case your original sorting is important to you.

Using INDEX MATCH, sorting is not relevant.

```
=INDEX($T$2:$T$9,MATCH(Q2,$S$2:$S$9,0))
```

INDEX("RANGE TO RETURN AS ANSWER", MATCH("WHAT TO FIND", "RANGE TO FIND IT",0))

[image]